# Tomcat 404 when using class

Tags: tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I have a Tomcat server running with index.jsp but when I add the .class servlet it turns the index.jsp into Not found 404.

This is my web.xml in /opt/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF

```
// Servlets
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tyd.gr1.la.login</servlet-class>
</servlet>

// Servlet Mappings
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My index.jsp is located in /opt/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT

If I remove the login.class in /opt/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/tyd/gr1/la and start tomcat I get presented with the index.jsp

But if I put login.class back I get HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
    Type Status Report

```
Message Not found

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0p6l.png)

Comment: why are you trying to install into the `ROOT` webapp?

Comment: `WEB-INF` is supposed to be placed directly under `webapp`

Comment: I found the "Tomcat is properly configured" index.html there so I replaced it with my own index.jsp. It shows but when I add a java .class suddenly I get 404

Comment: @wingchun1274 please post a proper screen shot of your directory structure and also what url you are entering

Comment: @wingchun1274 what method have you mapped inside your login.java class to handle '/' path ?

Comment: @Ramanlfc I have posted the Screenshot in Screenshot1

Comment: are you really just pasting in a .class file ???

Comment: @Harshal On my Windows PC I made a .java that uses the data from a form in the index.jsp to check against a database. In IntelliJ IDE the .java works with the index.jsp. I used javac and the neccesary libraries on my pi to compile the .java into .class so I can put it in Tomcat.

Comment: @Ramanlfc After I moved `WEB-INF` under  `webapps`. Tomcat doesn't make a link to the `login.class` anymore. In my `index.jsp` it is `<form method="post" action="login">`. Now after I press submit it gives an `error 404 for /login`

Answer (score 0):

I have just been fighting this. Some things that helped me:

- check your web.xml has correct spelling of tags such as `<servlet>`
- check your naming in `<servlet-class></servlet-class>`

  i.e. `<servlet-class>com.tyd.gr1.la.login</servlet-class>`
- build as a war and let Tomcat deploy. It will likely use:
  `webapps/WEB-INF/classes/com/tyd/gr1/la` note the ROOT is dropped
- note case sensitivity. For me in one example

  `<form action=\"HelloWorld\" method=\"POST\">\r\n")`  - BROKE giving
  a 404

  `<form action=\"helloworld\" method=\"POST\">\r\n")`  - worked
- If you are still struggling start to comment out your xml.web declarations to isolate what is breaking. I found I could reach assets and HTML pages, JSPs and other elements until I finally fixed the class naming and it all worked.

Comment: This was a long time ago, I think I avoided this by deploying it via a .war file instead of manually putting it in directories.